# Erro com resultados da Barra de pesquisa

Tags: javascript, html

Eu tenho um campo de busca onde eu digito o termo e ele busca referências no banco de dados, tudo certo até aí. Acontece que quando apago e deixo o `input` de pesquisa em branco, ele continua exibindo os resultados.

Isso só muda se eu escrever outra coisa, mas eu queria que a caixa sumisse caso não tivesse nada escrito. Como posso corrigir isso?

Esses são o `HTML` e o `JS` que usei para fazer. Já postei uma outra dúvida com esse mesmo projeto mas já foi resolvido.

**Barra de Pesquisa [HTML]**

```
<form id="searchForm">
        <div class="inner-form">
            <div class="input-field second-wrap">
                <input id="busca" name="pesquisar" type="text" placeholder="Qual serviço você está procurando?" />
                <div style="background: #efefef;">
                    <ul id='results' style='list-style: none;margin: 0;'>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field third-wrap">
                <button class="btn-search" id="btnSearch" type="button">
                Pesquisar
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**Funções OnKeyUp**

```
document.getElementById("busca").onkeyup = function (e) {
        if(e.keyCode >= 65 && e.keyCode <= 90) {
            var q = this.value === "" ? "*" : this.value;
            sendSearch(q);
        }
    };
```

**Requisição das informações**

```
function sendSearch(q) {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "/sistema/Teste.php?val="+q, true);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if(xmlhttp.readyState===4&&xmlhttp.status===200) {
                var json = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                var resultado = "";
                for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++)
                    resultado +=
                        "<li style='padding: 7px 0'><a data-click='' data-target='" + json[i].id +"' style='color: #48556b;' href='" + json[i].uri + "'><h5 class='m-0'>"+ json[i].nome +"</h5></a></li>";
                document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = resultado;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

**Esta foto é a pesquisa sendo feita**
[image: Aqui está]

**Esta foto é quando eu apago. Quero entender o que fazer para que quando eu apagar o termo, essa caixa de resultados também sumir.**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tem alguém que pode me ajudar a entender esse processo?

Grato.

=========================================

#### RESOLUÇÃO COM BASE NAS RESPOSTAS FORNECIDAS:

Consegui resolver o problema, usando a resposta do usuário @lvr7. 
Lá em cima acrescentei o código de um `onKeyup` que uso e agora reposto com as modificações que usei para fazer a funcionalidade dar certo. Relembrando que eu queria que quando não houvesse texto no `input` a `div` de resultados ficaria oculta. Consegui isso acrescentando um `style='display:none;'` na div de resultados (id="results"). Veja:

```
<ul id='results' style='list-style: none;margin: 0;display:none;'></ul>
```

E o código `onkeyup`:

```
document.getElementById("busca").onkeyup = function (e) {
        if(e.keyCode >= 65 && e.keyCode <= 90 || e.keyCode === 8) {
            var q = this.value === "" ? "*" : this.value;
            if(q === "*") {
                document.getElementById('results').style.display = 'none';
                sendSearch(q);
            } else {
                document.getElementById('results').style.display = 'block';
                sendSearch(q);
            }

        }
    };
```

Muito fácil e estava criando cabeças onde não tinha, haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie um event listener no input. 
O event listener "escuta" por alterações, e dispara uma função. 
Ficaria assim

```
Var inputBusca = Document.getElementById('busca');
Var lista = document.getElementById('results');
Inputbusca.addEventListener('onchange', function(){ 
  If (Inputbusca.value == "") {
        lista.style.display = 'none'
} else {
        lista.style.display = 'block'
}
})
```

Espero ter ajudado.
A formatação está ruim pois fiz no cel

Comment: Mano, rsrsrsrs, com certeza não deu certo utilizar esse código mas me abriu os olhos para umas 2 outras formas de realizar essa funcionalidade e uma delas deu certo, muito obrigado pela sugestão e ajuda. O `onchange` não funcionou, tratei apenas com o `onkeyup` acrescentando outra condicional que foi usada ali no seu exemplo. Vlw msm. Se puder validar positivo na minha pergunta mano, para mostrar a utilidade da pergunta e a bom formulação da pergunta eu agradeço. :)